# Star Wars Universe - ship designations

Tags: star-wars

Many ships in the Star Wars franchise are named after their look: Y-wing, X-wing, K-wing etc.

As the main alphabet in use is [Aurebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh) , why not name the ships after that?

Looking at the link for Aurebesh, the closest thing to our letter Y is "Vev" (representing our letter V), so why not call it Vev-wing?